# data.table is slow compared to data.frame for group filtering

Tags: r, data.table

data.table is slow if I filter based on numeric value (greater than or less than)

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(paste("group", 0:2000, sep = ""), 7000, replace = TRUE),
                pvalue = 10^(sample(seq(from = -5, to = -1, by = 0.1), 7000, replace = TRUE)))
groups <- setdiff(unique(df$group), "group0")
# data.frame takes 0.16 sec
system.time( lapply(groups, function(r) {
          df.temp <- df[df$group == r,]
          any(df.temp[["pvalue"]] < 0.01, na.rm = TRUE)
      }))

DT <- as.data.table(df)
setkeyv(DT, c("group"))
# data.table takes 0.9 sec
system.time(lapply(groups, function(r) any(DT[.(r), pvalue <= 0.01], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Does anyone know, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `data.table` correctly. It is expensive to call `DT[` many times. Instead you could do something like the following

```
setkeyv(DT, c("group"))
DT[!("group0"), any(pvalue <= 0.01), by = group]

          group   V1
   1:    group1 TRUE
   2:   group10 TRUE
   3:  group100 TRUE
   4: group1000 TRUE
   5: group1001 TRUE
```

Comment: Right. However, now I need to modify the code to save the output and use it in `lapply` instead of calculating it inside the `lapply` function.

Comment: Is there a way to get indices of a key in a fast way? Like in this case, `DT[.("group1"), which =T]` would work but it would be slow inside the lapply.